# What does [?1049h and [?1h ANSI escape sequences do?

Tags: less, escape-characters

When I used shell in a box and when I call less command (`echo foo | less`) in ajax response there was this code:

```
\u001B[?1049h\u001B[?1h\u001B=\rfoo\r\n\u001B[7m(END)\u001B[27m\u001B[K
```

what does `\u001B[?1049h` and `\u001B[?1h` escape sequences do, also what is `\u001B=`? Are they documented somewhere?

Comment: Found `Esc[?1h` in http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php but what about `Esc[?1049h`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\u001B` is an unnecessarily verbose ASCII escape character, which seems to have been introduced for [ECMAScript6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/).  POSIX would use octal `\033`, and some others allow hexadecimal `\01b`.  The upper/lower case of the number is irrelevant.

The `\u001B[?1049h` (and `\u001B[?1049l`) are escape sequences which tell [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) to *optionally* switch to and from the alternate screen.

- The question mark shows that it is "private use" (a category set aside for implementation-specific features in the standard).  About a third of the private-use modes listed in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) correspond to one of DEC's (those have a mnemonic such as `DECCKM` in their descriptions).  The others are either original to xterm, or adapted from other terminals, as noted.
- The reason for this escape sequence is to provide a terminfo-based way to let users decide whether programs can use the alternate screen.  According to the [xterm manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html):

> **`titeInhibit`** (class **`TiteInhibit`**)
>   Specifies whether or not xterm should remove **`ti`** and **`te`**  termcap
>   entries (used to switch between alternate screens on startup of
>   many screen-oriented programs) from  the  TERMCAP  string.   If
>   set,  xterm  also  ignores the escape sequence to switch to the
>   alternate screen.  Xterm supports terminfo in a different  way,
>   supporting  composite  control sequences (also known as private
>   modes) **`1047`**, **`1048`** and **`1049`** which have the same  effect  as  the
>   original **`47`** control sequence.  The default for this resource is
>   "false".

The 1049 code (introduced in [1998](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_90)) is *recognized* by most terminal emulators which claim to be xterm-compatible, but most do not make the feature *optional*.  So they don't really implement the feature.

On the other hand, `\u001B[?1h` did not originate with xterm, but (like `\u001B=`) is from DEC VT100s, used for switching the terminal to use *application mode* for cursor keys (DECCKM) and the numeric keypad (DECKPAM).  These are used by programs such as `less` when initializing the terminal because terminal descriptions use application (or normal) mode escape sequences for special keys to ***match*** the initialization strings given in these terminal descriptions.

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite) (xterm FAQ)
- [Why can't I use the cursor keys in (whatever) shell?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows) (xterm FAQ)
- [My cursor keys do not work](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode) (ncurses FAQ)
- [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)

Comment: Actually, it's normally \x1b for hexademical escape, not \01b as the leading 0 normally implies octal.

Comment: The question was about ECMAscript, which does not use octal (and the `\u` escape is supposed to be distinct).

Answer (score 1):

`ESC[?1049h` seems to be from the *DEC Private Mode Set*:

> Save cursor as in DECSC and use Alternate
>             Screen Buffer, clearing it first.  (This may be disabled by
>             the titeInhibit resource).  This combines the effects of the 1
>             0 4 7  and 1 0 4 8  modes.  Use this with terminfo-based
>             applications rather than the 4 7  mode.

http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_

Note that `CSI` translates to `ESC[`.