# How to fix anoying vim/terminal behaviour (vim produces empty lines in terminal)?

Tags: terminal, vim

Everytime when I start vim in new terminal or use clear command before starting vim, it produces empty lines in terminal. How to fix this?

[image]

My term is set to `xterm-256color`. I cleared my `.vimrc`, because I thought it was the problem, but it didn't help. I'm using terminator 1.91, but I've also tried default gnome terminal. vim 8.0 and my system is Manjaroo Linux.

Comment: @Christopher "if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
  PS1='\[\033[01;31m\][\h\[\033[01;36m\] \W\[\033[01;31m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '
 else
  PS1='\[\033[01;32m\][\u@\h\[\033[01;37m\] \W\[\033[01;32m\]]\$\[\033[00m\] '
 fi
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It does not produce empty lines.

It moves the cursor to the bottom left-hand corner of the screen, which is where it happens to be sent when you issue a command like `:q` or `ZZ`, usually because you have just entered an `ex` command or because it has updated the status line.

And it only does so because your terminal description in `terminfo` either does not include capabilities for entering and exiting *cursor addressing mode* at all, or includes enter/exit cursor addressing mode capabilities that do not employ the DECSM/DECRM Private Mode sequences that command saving/restoring the cursor position *in addition to* commanding switching to and from the alternate screen buffer, and do not explictly make up for that deficiency by including DECSC/DECRC as well. (DEC Private Modes 1047 and 47 only command switching to and from the alternate screen buffer.  It is DEC Private Mode 1049 that commands saving/restoring the cursor position as well.)

Normally, immediately upon exiting `vim`, like other programs that present a *full screen textual user interface*, exits cursor addressing mode.  Because that restores the cursor position from when it *entered* cursor addressing mode, back when `vim` and such programs started up their full-screen textual user interfaces in the first place, the cursor is thereby moved from the bottom left-hand corner to wherever it was when the program started.

That lack of `terminfo` capabilities, in turn, is most probably because you have not used the correct description for your terminal/terminal emulator.  The most common error is to abuse `xterm`, exactly as you are doing it transpires.  Unless your terminal emulator *really is the XTerm program*, that terminal type is wrong for your terminal.  Use [`iTerm.App`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-i_Term_App), [`vte-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-vte-256color), [`tmux-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-tmux-256color), [`putty-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty-256color), [`nsterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-nsterm), [`terminator`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-terminator), and so forth, as appropriate.

Note that the terminal emulators that are built into the Linux, OpenBSD, NetBSD, and FreeBSD kernels themselves, denoted by the [`linux-16color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-linux-16color), [`pccon`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-pccon), and  [`pcvt25`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-pcvt25) terminal types, do not have alternative screen buffer mechanisms and so do not have `terminfo` capabilities for entering/exiting cursor addressing mode, and this is the *only* behaviour that you will get from any full-screen program on such terminals.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243320/5132
- https://superuser.com/a/715563/38062
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336635/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419092/5132
- Thomas E. Dickey (2018). "[What versions are available?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#other_versions-id)". *XTerm FAQ*. invisible-island.net.
- [What does [?1049h and [?1h ANSI escape sequences do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288962/)

Comment: Terminator and gnome-terminal both use the VTE terminal emulator widget. VTE, and hence these apps, set `TERM=xterm-256color` by default, this is what its developers test it with, and this is what most users use it with. This is not ideal, but the other possible approach (having its own terminal description) has problems too. Out of two problematic approaches the project chose this one.

Comment: [It is, nonetheless, wrong.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375784/5132)